# MS Access [VBA/SQL] change time in date/time field only

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I would like to update the time portion of every record to 00:00 so that I can group by day.
So for example 01-Apr-2022 4:18:00 PM would become 01-Apr-2022 00:00.

I don't mind if this is SQL or VBA - whatever is more efficient & gets the job done.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to transform within GROUP BY? If so I'd love to learn that, if not changing permanently will work too

Comment: So, Date-Times in Access AND Excel are floating point numbers whose integer parts are days since 1/1/1900 and whose fractional parts represent the fraction of the 24 hour day.  Access is perfectly happy to treat dates as numbers, so you can truncate the the time portion out (turn them all to midnight) with Int(table_date).

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using DateValue in GROUP BY.

Answer (score -1):

If your date is stored like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:

`update TABLE set table_date = (select convert(varchar, table_date, 23) from TABLE where id = table_id) + ' 00:00:00' where id = table_id`

The idea is to get the first part of your date yyyy-mm-dd and concatenate with 00:00:00.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I can see how that would work. I used DateValue([Date/Time]) in my GROUP BY which gave me the output I was looking for